# How to store multi line SQL query in app.config file in .Net

Tags: asp.net

Could you please help me , How to store **multi line SQL query in app.config file**.

below is Example:- I want to store this query in App.config file.

```
select * from users u LEFT join Employee E on u.id = E.id
Inner Join Department D on d.id=E.id
Left Join Orders O On O.Id = E.id
Inner Join Values V v.id = E.id 
WHERE
u.createTime>=Getdate()-1 AND u.deletstatus=1
AND D.Id<>0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to split a string across multiple lines in an XML file? If so, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184097/is-it-possible-to-split-a-string-across-multiple-lines-in-an-xml-file-if-so-ho)

Comment: please refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652751/multi-line-text-in-a-web-config-file

Comment: No sir, that didn't fix my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, you can have a multi-line string in XML. Maybe you didn't escape the XML special chracters:

```
Ampersand       &amp;   &
Less-than       &lt;    <
Greater-than    &gt;    >
Quotes          &quot;  "
Apostrophe      &apos;  '
```

Here is the XML for your App.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SqlQuery" 
       value="select * from users u LEFT join Employee E on u.id = E.id
              Inner Join Department D on d.id=E.id
              Left Join Orders O On O.Id = E.id
              Inner Join Values V v.id = E.id 
              WHERE
              u.createTime&gt;=Getdate()-1 AND u.deletstatus=1
              AND D.Id&lt;&gt;0" />
</appSettings>
```